# deploy web application and web service remotely - 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I created a web application and WCF web service in VS2010.  It works fine locally. I want to deploy the web application and service to a test server.  The application and service will be on the same server.  I published the app and service to the server and created an Application Pool for the App, Paging. I added the application and service to the Site folder in IIS and converted them to applications.

When I try to access the application I get a 404 error.  I believe it is because I need to start the web service.  When it runs locally, I start the web service from a VS2010 project and then start the web application.  Don't I also have to start the web service on the web server? How do I do that?

The application and web service folders are in the folders: C:\inetpub\wwwroot2\PagingService and C:\inetpub\wwwroot2\PagingTool. When accessing the web service I tried, http://localhost/PagingService/PagingService.Paging.svc, I get the error:
**The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Ntlm') do not allow those configured on the binding 'WSHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').**

The application and web service works fine on my local machine, do I have to change the authentication because it is on a web server?  The OS is Windows Server 2008.

This is my app.config file for my connection:

```
<services>
  <service name="PagingService.Paging" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPaging" contract="PagingService.IPaging">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/PagingService/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPaging"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
            maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
            sendTimeout="00:25:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
             maxArrayLength="200000000"
             maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In your IIS make sure you have Anonymous Authentication set as "Enabled" for your web service.

Comment: Thanks! After changing that setting I was able to connect to the web service locally but using http://localhost/PagingService/PagingService.Paging.svc.  But when I try to start the application remotely, I am getting a 500 error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems in the web.config file the ReportViewerWebControlHandler entry is giving this error:  **Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'ReportViewerWebControlHandler'**

Comment: I removed this entry, ReportViewerWebControlHandler, and the application is now working

Comment: @Hakunamatata - Add an answer to this question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IIS make sure you have Anonymous Authentication set as "Enabled" for your web service.

[image]